# Tsconfig `paths` equivalent for normal JS node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this on a TypeScript project, it's a nice config option on `tsconfig.json` that lets me create aliases for the folders

```json
{
"compilerOptions": {
  "paths": {
    "@src/*": ["src/*"],
    "@images/*": ["src/assets/images/*"],
    "@styles/*": ["src/assets/styles/*"],
    "@components": ["src/components"],
    "@layout/*": ["src/layout/*"],
    "@pages/*": ["src/pages/*"]
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do the same on a project that does not use TypeScript, just regular Javascript in node with ES6 modules on?

Answer (score 2):

I found that node already has something called [`Subpath imports`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/all.html#packages_subpath_imports), is not exactly the same but it works for me. For anyone looking for something similar, this just uses `#` instead of `@`:

on the `package.json`

```json
"imports": {
  "#src": "./src/*",
  "#controllers/*": ["./src/controllers/*"],
  "#routes/*": ["./src/routes/*"]
}
```

And then import on your app, – In this case I use ES modules:

```js
import File from '#routes/file.js'
```